# Can you use Karate Framework to do Desktop based automation?

Tags: karate, desktop-application

My team is using Karate framework for doing UI and API testing. However, we do have some windows desktop-based applications/simulators which we need to interact with for completing end to end automation. Is there a way we can use Karate for desktop-based automation?

Looking for answers on how to achieve Desktop based automation using Karate framework.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. But my recommendation is evaluate it and do a PoC. Because depending on how "automatable" your application is, your mileage may vary. Note that the code is very maintainable - so if you or your team can dig in and contribute, I would say you should seriously consider Karate for Windows desktop automation.

Your starting point should be here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-robot